Generate Sitemap after removing JetPack
I was using JetPack, but I've since removed it.  Since disabling the plugin, my sitemaps haven't been updating.
The existing site maps are there, but new posts aren't being added to them.
wp_sitemaps_get_server()->sitemaps_enabled() returns true.
I'm on the latest WordPress Version, 6.6.2.
If I manually remove a category, then wp-sitemap-taxonomies-category-1.xml is automatically updated.
But whenever I post a new blog post, wp-sitemap-posts-post-2.xml doesn't update.
Is there any way to restore the built-in WordPress sitemap functionality without a 3rd party plugin?

Have you tried reinitializing the permalinks?
Settings > Permalinks > Save Changes
